# pride vs. proudness

Tags: word-usage

Until yesterday I did not even know that the noun proudness exists. I always thought pride was the only possible noun for the adjective proud. Is there actually a difference between the two nouns (pride and proudness) or can they be used interchangeably in every case?

Comment: Have you googled (or search google books) for some examples of usage?  It would help potential answers or even answer the question for you.

Comment: This would be improved if you cited a dictionary to show that it does exist.  The OED is subscription, so I can't link; but it gives the meanings 1. Pride, arrogance, haughtiness.
†2. Proud show, splendour, magnificence. Obs.

Comment: Don't use the longer word. If it ever was an acceptable word, it is obsolete now, and anybody reading it would think you made a mistake and meant 'pride'. Just use 'pride'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what the OED says:

***proudness*** Now rare. [f. *proud* a. + -*ness*. ] The quality of being proud; pride.

1. Lofty self-esteem, arrogance, haughtiness.

   - 1500-20 Dunbar *Poems* ix. 116, I synnit..In he exaltit arrogance and folye, Prowdnes, derisioun, scorne and vilipentioun.
   - 1552 Latimer *Serm. Gospels* iv. 173 He fell..in suche a hatred and proudenes agaynst God.
   - 1588 A. King tr. *Canisius' Catech*. K j, Thair proudnes is intolerable.
   - 1860 Pusey *Min. Proph.* 465 Isaiah accumulates words, to express the haughtiness of Moab..as if we were to say `pride, prideful, proudness, pridefulness'.
   - 1902 E. H. Cooper *20th Century Child* xii. (1905) 231 They [crabs] should be kept in a bucket for a week, said a small child firmly, `to calm down their proudness'.
2. Proud show, splendour, magnificence.

   - 1606 Warner *Alb. Eng*. xvi. ci. 401 Nature wrongd by Arte, of Prowdnes more than need.

As can be seen, the most recent cited use (not mention) of *proudness* by an adult was in 1606 and was spelled *Prowdnes*. The OED says it's "now rare".

But what you say or write is up to you, as always.

Comment: There is another definition of *proud* which means to stick out or to be raised.  "The saw cut left the wood *proud* of the surface by a sixteenth of an inch."  I'd use *proudness* in describing that quality rather than *pride*.  Of course I'd probably rewrite the sentence to avoid it altogether...